# Plot a surface only for coordinates that satisfy a specific equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, surface

I have two grid coordinates matrices, `X` and `Y`, created by calling `[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y)`, so their elements represent coordinates. How can I plot a surface on the xy-plane, using heights from matrix `V`, only for coordinates that satisfy a specific equation? For example, my plot extends up to radius `a`, but I dont want to plot any data to the set of points that satisfy the equation sqrt(x^2 + (y-c)^2) < b, where `b`, `c` (`a>b`) are given constants and `x=X(i,j), y=Y(i,j)`. Is there an easy way to do this, other than creating the two grid coordinates matrices (up to radius `a`) and then manually removing elements from `X`, `Y`, `V`, using nested for loops? I have not found any way to limit the plotting area I am interested in by changing `x`, `y`.

Comment: make `v` `NaN`. say you can make `v(x>5 && mod(y/3)==0)=NaN`, then just `surf`. All NaNs wont be plotted

Comment: @AnderBiguri How do you write this in MATLAB? I think that this line does not work without for loops.

Comment: Incorrect, that line is perfectly valid matlab. Read about "logical indexing", or just, give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Logical Indexing

Just in case you're still looking for any implementation details. Referencing the comment by **@Ander Biguri**. I have to add that it might be easier to use mesh parameters `X` and `Y` directly in the logical indexing. Here is a little playground script that might help future readers. Below `Region_Array` is a logical array that specifies where the condition in this case `sqrt(X.^2 + (Y-c).^2) < b` is true. When true `Region_Array` is indexed with the value "1" and elsewhere with "0". I've split this into two steps just in case the complementary region is quickly wanted. The images/plots below show the resulting `surf()` and masks/regions. MATLAB has some thorough documentation and examples overviewing logical indexing: [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)

### Trivial Surface Plot:

[image: Eliminating Surf Portions]

### Masks/Regions Not to be Plotted:

[image: Corresponding Regions]

### Playground Script:

```
%Random test axes%
x = linspace(0,100,50);
y = linspace(0,100,50);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

%Trivial plot of ones%
V = ones(length(x),length(y));

%Constant parameters%
b = 20;
c = 10;

%Eliminating within the curved region%
figure(1)
Region_Array = sqrt(X.^2 + (Y-c).^2) < b;
V(Region_Array) = NaN;
subplot(1,2,1); surf(X,Y,V);
axis([0 100 0 100]);
title("Eliminating Within the Curved Region");

%Eliminating outside the curved region%
V = ones(length(x),length(y));
V(~Region_Array) = NaN;
subplot(1,2,2); surf(X,Y,V);
axis([0 100 0 100]);
title("Eliminating Outside the Curved Region");

figure(2)
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(~Region_Array,'InitialMagnification',200);
title("Region Array Mask/Map (Inside)")
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Region_Array,'InitialMagnification',200);
title("Region Array Mask/Map (Outside)")
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Great detailed answer :)